# aggregate values of json without specifying key in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table which has data like id, country, city,core_usage,memory_usage. Core_usage and memory_usage is a JSON array field which has values like [{'0':100.0},{'1':90.0},{'2':80.0}---{'n':80.0}] against a row in table, so row in table looks like

| id | country | city | core_usage | memory_usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usa | new-york | [{'0':100.0},{'1':90.0},{'2':80.0},{'3':80.0}] | [{'0':1.0},{'1':20.0},{'2':30.0},{'3':40.0}] |
| 2 | usa | new-york | [{'0':50.0}] | [{'0':10.0}] |
| 3 | uk | London | [{'0':20.0},{'1':90.0},{'2':10.0},{'3':70.0},{'4':60.0},{'5':70.0}] | [{'0':1.0},{'1':20.0},{'2':30.0},{'3':40.0},{'4':20.0},{'5':10.0}] |

I want aggregated output as

| id | country | city | core_usage | memory_usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usa | new-york | 350 | 91 |
| 2 | usa | new-york | 50 | 10 |
| 3 | uk | London | 320 | 121 |

here keys in Core_usage and memory_usage can got upto n so want a way to aggregate them without using key, CTE clause and would appreciate if it can be done using json_value.

Comment: "[{'0':100.0},{'1':90.0},{'2':80.0},{'3':80.0}]" is not JSON...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With valid JSON you can do:

```
with data(id, country, city, core_usage, memory_usage) as (
    select 1, 'usa', 'new-york', '[{"0":100.0},{"1":90.0},{"2":80.0},{"3":80.0}]', '[{"0":1.0},{"1":20.0},{"2":30.0},{"3":40.0}]' from dual union all
    select 2, 'usa', 'new-york', '[{"0":50.0}]', '[{"0":10.0}]' from dual union all
    select 3, 'uk', 'London', '[{"0":20.0},{"1":90.0},{"2":10.0},{"3":70.0},{"4":60.0},{"5":70.0}]', '[{"0":1.0},{"1":20.0},{"2":30.0},{"3":40.0},{"4":20.0},{"5":10.0}]' from dual 
)
select id, country, city, 
    json_value(core_usage, '$[*].*.sum()') as core_usage,
    json_value(memory_usage, '$[*].*.sum()') as memory_usage
from data ;
```

Comment: what $[*].*.sum() mean over here?

Comment: It's the path: $[*] all items of the array, $[*].* all fields of each item